# Clarification on Taylor expansion in linear quadrupole multipole expansion in cartesian coordinates

Tags: electromagnetism, coordinate-systems, multipole-expansion

In my textbook, given the electric linear quadrupole on the z axis, as in the figure, the author considers the functions
$$
\frac{1}{r_i} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2+(z-z_i)^2}},
$$
with $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and  $r_i=\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2+ (z-z_i)^2}$,
to find the potential $P(x,y,z)$ due to the contribution of each of the charges. For the charge  on $P_1$ ($x_1=0$, $y_1=0$, $z_1$), $i=1$ it becomes
$$
\frac{1}{r_1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+(z-z1)^2}},
$$
and then does a Taylor expansion:
$$
\frac{1}{r_i} 
=\frac{1}{r} 
+ \left(\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x_i}} \frac{1}{x_i} \right) x_i 
+ \left(\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{y_i}} \frac{1}{y_i} \right) y_i 
+ \left(\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{z_i}} \frac{1}{z_i} \right) z_i 
+ \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial{^2}}{\partial{x_i^2}}\frac{1}{r_i}\right)x_i^2 
+ \cdots
$$
but the weird thing is that it's done with respect to the $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ coordinates, so for the $1/r_1$ function the Taylor expansion is done with respect to $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, for the $1/r_2$ function the Taylor expansion is done with respect to $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$  and so on, so he takes derivatives with respect to $x_i,y_i,z_i$ and the Taylor expansion is found around the point ($x_i=0$, $y_i=0$, $z_i=0$).

Isn't it supposed to be done with respect to the coordinates of the point where I am finding the potential, that is $P(x,y,z)$? how come he does it with respect to the coordinates of the charges? It doesn't seem correct to me. The functions are supposed to be functions of $x,y,z$, but he treats $1/r_1$ as a function of  $x_1,y_1,z_1$, $1/r_2$ as a function of $x_2,y_2,z_2$, etc., and then sums (by superposition) the potential of each charge corresponding to each of these functions, where each one seems to depend on different variables.

I attach the picture of the charge distribution and the solution of the problem for reference, it's in Italian but just focus on the math.
How do I make sense of it?

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

The object
$$
\frac{1}{r_i} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2+(z-z_i)^2}}
$$
is a function of six variables: $x_i$, $y_i$, $z_i$, $x$, $y$ and $z$. Of these, three are small, and three are big (respectively, $x_i$, $y_i$ and $z_i$, and $x$, $y$ and $z$). It is perfectly legitimate to take a Taylor expansion of this function with respect to only those variables which are small.

There is nothing problematic here.

Comment: the xi,yi,zi coordinates are supposed to be fixed, why should I see it as a function of 6 variables? instead of xi, yi,zi I might as well put any three numbers

Comment: They're still arbitrary numbers on which the value depends. That's what "function" means. The only reason to disregard that dependence is human prejudice.